# OpenOffice Base LIKE with columns

Tags: sql, database, openoffice.org, openoffice-base

I have an Open Office database. I'd like to use the LIKE operator with "%" marks between two columns in the same table:

```
SELECT * FROM "table1" WHERE UPPER ( "table1"."a" ) LIKE UPPER ('%' + "table1"."b" + '%' )
```

But it doesn't work, although

```
SELECT * FROM "table1" WHERE UPPER ( "table1"."a" ) LIKE UPPER ("table1"."b")
```

works. What's wrong in my syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing a + on the front after the % and before table.

```
SELECT [insert your fields here] FROM "table1" WHERE UPPER ( "table1"."a" ) LIKE UPPER ('%' + "table1"."b" + '%' )
```

### Updated

```
SELECT [insert your fields here] FROM "table1" WHERE UPPER ( "table1"."a" ) LIKE '%' + UPPER("table1"."b") + '%'
```

I'm assuming A and B are both of the same data type.

I'm assuming + is an string concat in openoffice.  other possible values are || or &

Comment: Sorry, I copied my code wrong. Your code (which is my original code) doesn't work. I'll edit my post

Comment: Thanks your help! That works. (But I can't understand why didn't my code work... OpenOffice is chaotic)

Comment: Wish I could tell you. I don't know open office database very well.  I just know to simplify operations when attempting to troubleshoot.

Comment: **Never use *, always define the fields.**

Comment: String concat is `||` in LibreOffice Base.